# Hibernate Criteria with restriction on children

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I got a simple class

```
@Entity(name = "tag")
public class Tag
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "tag", nullable = false)
    private String tag;

    public Tag()
    {
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTag()
    {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag)
    {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

And it resides as list in another class and is obtained using

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "entry_tag_list", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Tag> tags;
```

So when I create a Criteria using

```
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("tags.tag", tag));
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: tags.tag
```

I made sure that my getters and setters are getTags and setTags, so I am not sure what I am missing.

As a sidenote, I have to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` since a lot of queries depend on it.

Comment: You need to create a join to navigate in the association, as explained in the Criteria javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
cr.createAlias("tags", "tagsAlias");
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("tagsAlias.tag", tag);
```

Comment: To create join need to make alias.